# How to show Hyper links in chat to open the browser intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating an chat application. I have `EditText` where user can type and send message to other device. Now my issue is when user type a text something like **google.com** or **www.make.in**, I want to show it as  Hyper links in chat and on click of the lint i want to open the browser intent.

So how that can be done? Any Idea or suggestion will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:autoLink="all"` in your xml for the edit text.  This will convert SMS, URLs, phoen number, etc into clickable links.

Comment: I Try this out this ..buy in the chat list where each item show in an textView, it still appear as simple text instead of hyperLink text

Comment: Yeh its working now..but it crash whenever i tried to click on the link. This is the logcat http://pastebin.com/pcyVgu7N